# Authentication using ADAL in Xamarin.Forms will crash on iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory, adal

I used the latest version of ADAL (v3.13.8) in a Xamarin Forms app, 
using the guidance and sample published [here](https://github.com/michael-watson/Azure-MyExpenses/blob/master/MyExpenses.Mobile/iOS/Authenticator_iOS.cs).

For the first time, the iOS App will crash after user sign in. 
But it's fine when user try to login again.

The following are the error messages.

```
2017-02-06 15:41:24.215 HelperAPPiOS[4094:38377] 2/6/2017 7:41:24 AM:  - TokenCachePlugin.cs: **Failed to remove cache record**: -34018

2017-02-06 15:41:24.216 HelperAPPiOS[4094:38377] 2/6/2017 7:41:24 AM:  - TokenCache.cs: Serializing token cache with 1 items.

2017-02-06 15:41:24.220 HelperAPPiOS[4094:38377] 2/6/2017 7:41:24 AM:  - TokenCachePlugin.cs: **Failed to save cache record**: -34018
```

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code which causes this error?

Comment: I cannot sure which code will cause this issue.

Comment: The following is my code.
[link]https://github.com/jasonccliu/empHelper/blob/master/empHelper/empHelper.iOS/Service/AuthenticatorService.cs

Answer (score 0):

This should not cause your application to crash. Do you have a stacktrace that points to the library crashing?

Here is the line where the message is logged - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/ADAL.PCL.iOS/TokenCachePlugin.cs#L108

this is a common iOS error that is not resolved. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4743?tstart=0

Comment: Try to deploy App on iOS Simulator and it will be crashed with second login. 
(The first time login was successful)

The error log is as follows.

[link](https://github.com/jasonccliu/empHelper/blob/master/iOSCrashLog)

I don't know how to find key issue in my system.log.
Please give me some advice, thanks.